# C# list - finding the occurrence of elements and adding a position counter to the list

Tags: c#

I need some help on this puzzle with list manipulation. I'm not sure how to go about solving this.

I have a list of data and I need to add an occurrence counter id to each row where the date is grouped and the amount are matched.

e.g on same day if the amounts are the same then increase the counter id for each time they are the same

Original list of data

```
text    | date       | amount
memo 01 | 2022-05-25 | 10
memo 02 | 2022-05-25 | 20
memo 03 | 2022-05-25 | 20
memo 04 | 2022-05-25 | 30
memo 05 | 2022-05-25 | 15
memo 06 | 2022-05-25 | 20
memo 07 | 2022-05-25 | 10
memo 08 | 2022-05-25 | 40
memo 09 | 2022-05-26 | 20
memo 10 | 2022-05-26 | 15
memo 11 | 2022-05-26 | 30
memo 12 | 2022-05-26 | 20
```

Output desired (with occurrence counter added)

```
text    | date       | amount | occur
memo 01 | 2022-05-25 |   10   | 1
memo 02 | 2022-05-25 |   20   | 1
memo 03 | 2022-05-25 |   20   | 2
memo 04 | 2022-05-25 |   30   | 1
memo 05 | 2022-05-25 |   15   | 1
memo 06 | 2022-05-25 |   20   | 3
memo 07 | 2022-05-25 |   10   | 2
memo 08 | 2022-05-25 |   40   | 1
memo 09 | 2022-05-26 |   20   | 1
memo 10 | 2022-05-26 |   15   | 1
memo 11 | 2022-05-26 |   30   | 1
memo 12 | 2022-05-26 |   20   | 2
```

Here's my code to create my test list of data

```
var myList = new List<(string, DateTime, decimal)> 
     {
         ("memo 01",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),10),
         ("memo 02",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),20),
         ("memo 03",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),20),
         ("memo 04",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),30),
         ("memo 05",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),15),
         ("memo 06",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),20),
         ("memo 07",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),10),
         ("memo 08",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),40),
         ("memo 09",new DateTime(2022, 05, 26),20),
         ("memo 10",new DateTime(2022, 05, 26),15),
         ("memo 11",new DateTime(2022, 05, 26),30),
         ("memo 12",new DateTime(2022, 05, 26),20)
       };

myList.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.Item1} | {x.Item2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")} | {x.Item3}"));
```

Comment: Upvote for using ISO date format!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using Dictionaries but expanded for better understanding.

```
    var myList = new List<(string text, DateTime date, decimal occurence)>
 {
     ("memo 01",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),10),
     ("memo 02",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),20),
     ("memo 03",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),20),
     ("memo 04",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),30),
     ("memo 05",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),15),
     ("memo 06",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),20),
     ("memo 07",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),10),
     ("memo 08",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),40),
     ("memo 09",new DateTime(2022, 05, 26),20),
     ("memo 10",new DateTime(2022, 05, 26),15),
     ("memo 11",new DateTime(2022, 05, 26),30),
     ("memo 12",new DateTime(2022, 05, 26),20)
   };
        //final output list
        var output = new List<(string text, DateTime date, decimal occurence, int count)>();

        //dictionary to store the counts
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (var item in myList)
        {
            var key = $"{item.date}_{item.occurence}";
            if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out int count))
            {
                //populate the output list
                output.Add((item.text, item.date, item.occurence, count + 1));

                //update dictionary
                dictionary[key] += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                //populate the output list
                output.Add((item.text, item.date, item.occurence, 1));

                //update dictionary
                dictionary[key] = 1;
            }
        }

        output.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.text} | {x.date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")} | {x.occurence} | {x.count}"));
```

Comment: Had you used `new Dictionary<(DateTime date, decimal occurence), int>` (rather than create a `string` key) and if you had moved the `output.Add` outside of the `if`, then I think I would like your answer a whole lot more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Dictionary* to count occurrences:

```
  ...

  Dictionary<(DateTime, decimal), int> occs = new();

  foreach (var x in myList) {
    if (!occs.TryAdd((x.Item2, x.Item3), 1))
      occs[(x.Item2, x.Item3)] += 1;

    Console.WriteLine($"memo {x.Item1} | {x.Item2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")} | {x.Item3} | {occs[(x.Item2, x.Item3)]}");
  }
```

**Outcome:**

```
memo 01 | 2022-05-25 | 10 | 1
memo 02 | 2022-05-25 | 20 | 1
memo 03 | 2022-05-25 | 20 | 2
memo 04 | 2022-05-25 | 30 | 1
memo 05 | 2022-05-25 | 15 | 1
memo 06 | 2022-05-25 | 20 | 3
memo 07 | 2022-05-25 | 10 | 2
memo 08 | 2022-05-25 | 40 | 1
memo 09 | 2022-05-26 | 20 | 1
memo 10 | 2022-05-26 | 15 | 1
memo 11 | 2022-05-26 | 30 | 1
memo 12 | 2022-05-26 | 20 | 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my ***updated*** LINQ only way.

It uses a `Aggregate` operator to fairly clearly compute the result. It uses an inefficient `Count` operator, but the logic is as simple as possible, so for short lists this is quite a clean way to go.

```
var output =
    list
        .Aggregate(
            new
            {
                counter = new List<(DateTime date, decimal amount)>(),
                output = new List<(string text, DateTime date, decimal amount, int occur)>()
            },
            (a, x) =>
            {
                a.counter.Add((x.date, x.amount));
                a.output.Add((x.text, x.date, x.amount, a.counter.Count(y => y == (x.date, x.amount))));
                return new { a.counter, a.output };
            },
            a => a.output);
```

Start with this data:

```
var list = new List<(string text, DateTime date, decimal amount)>
{
    ("memo 01",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),10),
    ("memo 02",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),20),
    ("memo 03",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),20),
    ("memo 04",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),30),
    ("memo 05",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),15),
    ("memo 06",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),20),
    ("memo 07",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),10),
    ("memo 08",new DateTime(2022, 05, 25),40),
    ("memo 09",new DateTime(2022, 05, 26),20),
    ("memo 10",new DateTime(2022, 05, 26),15),
    ("memo 11",new DateTime(2022, 05, 26),30),
    ("memo 12",new DateTime(2022, 05, 26),20)
};
```

I get this result:

[image: output]

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to achieve the outcome you want:

```
var tempList = new List<(string, DateTime, decimal, int)>();
myList.ForEach(x => 
{
   x.Item4 = tempList.Where(y => y.Item2.Date == x.Item2.Date && y.Item3 == x.Item3 ).Count() + 1;
   tempList.Add(x);

   Console.WriteLine($"{x.Item1} | {x.Item2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")} | {x.Item3} | {x.Item4}");
});
```

Comment: Looks like I'd need to add the Item4 as an element when I create myList since I don't currently have that. But I think I understand what to do.

Comment: Essentially create an empty new list with extra 4th element I need, and then iterate through the original list and search the new list as it's built up to count the matches at the same time.

Comment: Adjusted your concept to this

`                var tempList = new List<(string, DateTime, decimal, int)>();
                int occurcounter;
                myList.ForEach(x =>
                {
                    
                    occurcounter = tempList.Where(y => y.Item2.Date == x.Item2.Date && y.Item3 == x.Item3).Count() + 1;
                    tempList.Add((x.Item1,x.Item2,x.Item3,occurcounter));

                });

                tempList.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.Item1} | {x.Item2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")} | {x.Item3} | {x.Item4}"));
`

Answer (score -1):

Here is a little `object-oriented` way.

```cs
public class Transactions : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Transaction, int>>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Transaction, int> _values = new();
    public void Add(Transaction transaction)
    {
        if (_values.ContainsKey(transaction))
        {
            _values[transaction] += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            _values.Add(transaction, 1);
        }
    }
    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<Transaction, int>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _values.GetEnumerator();
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
public record Transaction(DateTime Date, decimal Amount);
```

```cs
//Program.cs
var myList = new List<Transaction>
{
    new(new DateTime(2022, 05, 25), 10),
    new(new DateTime(2022, 05, 25), 20),
    new(new DateTime(2022, 05, 25), 20),
    new(new DateTime(2022, 05, 25), 30),
    new(new DateTime(2022, 05, 25), 15),
    new(new DateTime(2022, 05, 25), 20),
    new(new DateTime(2022, 05, 25), 10),
    new(new DateTime(2022, 05, 25), 40),
    new(new DateTime(2022, 05, 26), 20),
    new(new DateTime(2022, 05, 26), 15),
    new(new DateTime(2022, 05, 26), 30),
    new(new DateTime(2022, 05, 26), 20)
};
var output = new Transactions();
myList.ForEach(item => output.Add(item));
foreach (var keyValuePair in output)
{
    Console.WriteLine(keyValuePair);
}
```

Explanation: We have a record here which gives automatic value comparision, and then we create a custom collection to handle the new inserts.

Comment: Why is this object oriented?

Comment: Because the business logic and Data are together. Encapsulation.

Comment: What do you mean? It seems quite the opposite. You have your logic (which doesn't seem to be "business" logic) in the class `Transactions` and you have your data in a `record` called `Transaction`. And you've exposed the `Values` of the dictionary out of the class - which seems the opposite to encapsulation to me.

Comment: Initially, I had an IEnumerable with Values being private. Cleaned that up to make the answer a bit simpler. Let me make it proper then.

Comment: Code contains the correct behaviour now.

Comment: What about the `text` field?

Comment: There is no aggregation on the text field, so it can just be added to the Console.WriteLine. If there is a particular way, then we can add that as a field.

Comment: So, please show how you would do that with your code.

Answer (score -1):

After further consideration, a lot of the answers require ugly `if` statements when trying to use a dictionary to efficiently keep track of the counter. Here's a way to make the code much simpler.

Start with this extension method that encapsulates the ugly `if`:

```
public static class Ex
{
    public static int AddOrIncrement<T>(this Dictionary<T, int> source, T value)
    {
        if (source.ContainsKey(value))
            source[value] += 1;
        else
            source[value] = 1;
        return source[value];
    }
}
```

Now the final code is simple:

```
var output = new List<(string text, DateTime date, decimal amount, int occur)>();
var counter = new Dictionary<(DateTime date, decimal amount), int>();
foreach (var item in list)
{
    output.Add((item.text, item.date, item.amount, counter.AddOrIncrement((item.date, item.amount))));
}
```

This gives the correct output, identical to my other answer.

---

In for a penny, in for a pound...

So, my above answer leaves the state of the operation (the `counter` dictionary) exposed. It's not nicely encapsulated. We can also fix that.

Add this method:

```
IEnumerable<(string text, DateTime date, decimal amount, int occur)> Manipulate(IEnumerable<(string text, DateTime date, decimal amount)> source)
{
    var counter = new Dictionary<(DateTime date, decimal amount), int>();
    foreach (var item in source)
        yield return (item.text, item.date, item.amount, counter.AddOrIncrement((item.date, item.amount)));
}
```

Now that can be done locally or as part of the class.

Now the code required is this:

```
var output = Manipulate(list).ToList();
```

Same results as before.

---

And let's just go one step further.

The above `Manipulate` method is a little messy. Let's turn that into an extension method.

Here it is:

```
public static IEnumerable<R> Manipulate<T, K, R>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, K> key, Func<T, int, R> output)
{
    var counter = new Dictionary<K, int>();
    foreach (var item in source)
        yield return output(item, counter.AddOrIncrement(key(item)));
}
```

Now I think I have the cleanest, simplest, most efficient output:

```
var output =
    list
        .Manipulate(
            x => (x.date, x.amount),
            (x, n) => (x.text, x.date, x.amount, n))
        .ToList();
```

Same results as before.

---

Now, `Manipulate` as an extension method is a nice, but it's not as general-purpose as it could be. And its name doesn't tell us what it does. Let's make it a little more useful and also let's call it `CountByKey` and have it do this:

```
public static IEnumerable<(T item, int count)> CountByKey<T, K>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, K> key)
{
    var counter = new Dictionary<K, int>();
    foreach (var item in source)
        yield return (item, counter.AddOrIncrement(key(item)));
}
```

Now this has finally nailed the intent of the question in a simple generic method and we're back to consuming it in a LINQ query:

```
var output =
    list
        .CountByKey(x => (x.date, x.amount))
        .Select(x => (x.item.text, x.item.date, x.item.amount, x.count))
        .ToList();
```

It can't get much simpler, nor more readable, than that.

---

And, of course, we can pop back in the original signature of `Manipulate`, but with the name `CountByKey`:

```
public static IEnumerable<R> CountByKey<T, K, R>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, K> key, Func<T, int, R> output)
    => source.CountByKey(key).Select(x => output(x.item, x.count));
```

Finally we get this:

```
var output =
    list
        .CountByKey(
            x => (x.date, x.amount),
            (x, n) => (x.text, x.date, x.amount, n))
        .ToList();
```

A nice clear overload.